# Custom attribute issue

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I'm trying to get the "quantity" attribute of multiple Elements ID at the same time.

Here's what I tried :

```
productMinimum : document.getElementsById("id1","id2").getAttribute("quantity")
```

How can I make this work? The "id1" and "id2" elements all have the "quantity" attribute.

Here's what it looks like from the HTML side :

```
<li class="product" name="RD-101" id="id1" price="18" quantity="2">
<li class="product" name="RD-101" id="id2" price="18" quantity="4">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having is that `getElementsById()` doesn't exist (unless you've defined it elsewhere). What you *should* be using is `getElementById()`, albeit twice (as `getElementById()`, as its name implies, returns only *one* element, even if there are multiple elements with that same `id`, which is invalid mark-up, so please don't do that), and then pushing the returned elements into an array:

```
var products = [];
products.push(document.getElementById("id1"));
products.push(document.getElementById("id2"));
```

You could, of course, create your own function to return multiple elements based on their `id`:

```
function getElementsById(ids) {
    if (!ids) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var elems = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = ids.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (document.getElementById(ids[i])) {
                elems.push(document.getElementById(ids[i]));
            }
        }
        return elems;
    }
}

console.log(getElementsById(['id1','id3']));​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xj4WE/).

Bear in mind, though, that this returns a regular array, ***not*** a `nodeList` (as would be returned, for example, by `getElementsByClassName()`). And the returned array, even if it's only a single element, would have to be iterated over in the same way as any other array.

References:

- [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById).
- [`nodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList).
- [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Comment: So it would look like : productMinimum:document.getElementById("products").getAttribute("quantity") ? I'm not sure to understand. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, that seems like a valid use, assuming that you want to get the attribute-value of the attribute 'quantity' of the (single) element with an `id` of 'products'.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getQuantity(id) {
 return document.getElementById(id).getAttribute("quantity");
}

var quantId1 = getQuantity('id1');
var quantId2 = getQuantity('id2');
```

getElement**s**ById is returning an array.  You need to get the individual items.  If you had a whole lot of elements you could select by class product and write a simple function to loop over them and create an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get one element at once (with `getElementById()`). If you want an array containing the quantities, use this:

```
[document.getElementById('id1').getAttribute('quantity'), document.getElementById('id2').getAttribute('quantity')]
```

Consider using jQuery, there you can use `$('#id1, #id2')` and besides that it supports easy access to `data-` attributes - what you are doing right now is invalid HTML since `li` does not have `price` or `quantity` attributes:

```
<li class="product" name="RD-101" id="id1" data-price="18" data-quantity="2">
<li class="product" name="RD-101" id="id2" data-price="18" data-quantity="4">
```

To get the quantities array:

```
$('#id1, #id2').map(function() { return $(this).data('quantity'); }).get();
```

Comment: How would it look like using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function as `getElementsById`. you can use either `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementsByName`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

Take note that `getElementsByClassName` is fairly new and not supported by older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Using pure JavaScript you need to write your own function for that:

```
function getQuantities() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var quantityValue = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        quantityValue += document.getElementsById(args[i]).getAttribute("quantity");
    }
    return quantityValue;
}

// your code
productMinimum : getQuantities("id1","id2")
```

Answer (score 0):

As I [understand it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById), `document.getElementById` takes one id at the time

Also, consider using html5 custom [data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `getElementsById()`

But there is [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll), but it's [not supported in IE7 and older though](http://caniuse.com/#search=queryse)

[here's a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/WrWQK/) which should return the two `<li>` in a nodelist.

```
document.querySelectorAll('#id1, #id2')
```